# Excel formula: Union multiple ranges into 1 function argument

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have four dynamic ranges called `ADate`, `ALeadTime`, `BDate`,  and `BLeadTime` (two pairs) and a cell called `MyDate`.

Using array formulas I can easily find the mean of `LeadTime` based on the union of two different ranges within a given week by something like

```
{=AVERAGE(
    IF((ADate>=MyDate)*(ADate<MyDate+7),ALeadTime),
    IF((BDate>=MyDate)*(BDate<MyDate+7),BLeadTime))
}
```

This works well because `AVERAGE` accepts a variable number of arguments. However, if I want to use a different function such as `PERCENTILE` which only accepts a single argument this does not work.

How can I union the two ranges into one? I am aware of VBA's `Application.Union` but no VBA thanks. I have been messing around with something like

```
{=PERCENTILE(CHOOSE({1,2},
    IF((ADate>=MyDate)*(ADate<MyDate+7),ALeadTime)), 
    IF((BDate>=MyDate)*(BDate<MyDate+7),BLeadTime))), 0.8)
}
```

without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(IF((ADate>=MyDate)*(ADate<MyDate+7),ALeadTime)+IF((BDate>=MyDate)*(BDate<MyDate+7),BLeadTime)<>0,IF((ADate>=MyDate)*(ADate<MyDate+7),ALeadTime)+IF((BDate>=MyDate)*(BDate<MyDate+7),BLeadTime)),0.8)
```

Note, that it is an array formula, so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>